Flutter error while running app (Using FlutterDownloader and FlutterLocalNotifications)
I am trying to run the abb but I get the following error. I have attacked the gradle and manifest files. I am trying to get the hang of FlutterDownloader and FlutterLocalNotifications plugin for my app, but after following the instructions to change the gradle and manifest files, now my app does not even run.
Error:
E/AndroidRuntime(10309): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(10309): Process: com.example.task1, PID: 10309
E/AndroidRuntime(10309): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method addWindowLayoutInfoListener(Landroid/app/Activity;Lj$/util/function/Consumer;)V in class Landroidx/window/ex
tensions/layout/WindowLayoutComponent; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.window.extensions.layout.WindowLayoutComponent' appears in /system_ext/framework/androidx.window.extensions.jar)
E/AndroidRuntime(10309):        at androidx.window.layout.ExtensionWindowLayoutInfoBackend.registerLayoutChangeCallback(ExtensionWindowLayoutInfoBackend.kt:68)
E/AndroidRuntime(10309):        at androidx.window.layout.WindowInfoTrackerImpl$windowLayoutInfo$1.invokeSuspend(WindowInfoTrackerImpl.kt:52)
E/AndroidRuntime(10309):        at androidx.window.layout.WindowInfoTrackerImpl$windowLayoutInfo$1.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
E/AndroidRuntime(10309):        at androidx.window.layout.WindowInfoTrackerImpl$windowLayoutInfo$1.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
E/AndroidRuntime(10309):        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SafeFlow.collectSafely(Builders.kt:61)
E/AndroidRuntime(10309):        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.AbstractFlow.collect(Flow.kt:212)
E/AndroidRuntime(10309):        at androidx.window.java.layout.WindowInfoTrackerCallbackAdapter$addListener$1$1.invokeSuspend(WindowInfoTrackerCallbackAdapter.kt:96)
E/AndroidRuntime(10309):        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
E/AndroidRuntime(10309):        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(10309):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
E/AndroidRuntime(10309):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(10309):        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
E/AndroidRuntime(10309):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
E/AndroidRuntime(10309):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)

android\build.gradle:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2"
        classpath "org.jlleitschuh.gradle:ktlint-gradle:11.5.0"
    }
}


rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.android.library"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android"
apply plugin: "org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint"

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}


android {
    namespace 'com.example.task1'
    compileSdk 34
    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += "src/main/kotlin"
    }


    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 16
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
}

dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.2'
    implementation "androidx.core:core:1.3.0"
    implementation "androidx.media:media:1.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9"
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1"
    implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.5.0"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0"


}

app\build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.task1"
    compileSdk 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.task1"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dependencies {
        coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.2'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

main\AndroidManifest.xml:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <application
        android:label="task1"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <provider
            android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_downloader.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
        <!-- Begin FlutterDownloader customization -->
        <!-- disable default Initializer -->
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="merge">
            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup"
                tools:node="remove" />
        </provider>

        <!-- declare customized Initializer -->
        <provider
            android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.FlutterDownloaderInitializer"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter-downloader-init"
            android:exported="false">
            <!-- changes this number to configure the maximum number of concurrent tasks -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.MAX_CONCURRENT_TASKS"
                android:value="5" />
        </provider>
        <!-- End FlutterDownloader customization -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:showWhenLocked="true"
            android:turnScreenOn="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ActionBroadcastReceiver" />
    </application>
    <!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
         https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility?hl=en and
         https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.

         In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
</manifest>

Is there some error in permission handling or the gradle/manifest files?

Adding these lines in the dependencies sections of your android/app/build.gradle files works like butter:
coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.2'
implementation 'androidx.window:window:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0'

For more info:
Flutter chrash in Android 12l with "No interface method addWindowLayoutInfoListener"
